# Delete line until certain character with BASH

Tags: bash, erase

I have a file like this

```
1+1+1+1=4
-2.000000000000
2+1+2+1=6 
-4.000000000000 
3+1+3+1=8 
-4.828427124746
.....
```

and I would like to erase the character before the `=` in every line.

Then I would like to regroup the line two by two trying to get a table like this:

```
4 -2.000000000000
6 -4.000000000000
8 -4.828427124746
.....
```

Comment: That's all well and good, but what have you tried?

Comment: A "how do I do this" question is too broad.  Please indicate what you have tried and how it failed so we can see which parts you already understand and which parts you have trouble with.

Comment: How is this getting "find or recommend a book or tool" close votes rather than "too broad" close votes?

Comment: Ok! I will be more precise next time... It was my first post! :D

Comment: Welcome to the community! We're glad to have you, and not trying to be harsh -- part of our goal is to build a reusable knowledge base that's helpful to other people, and making questions as specific as possible makes them more reusable (since that focuses the question and the answer on exactly where the unexpected or misunderstood is, rather than including context that might make it less easy to find and reuse for someone with the same underlying problem but different surrounding circumstances).

Answer (score 4):

You could use sed and paste.

```
$ sed 's/^.*=//' file | paste -d' ' - -
4 -2.000000000000
6 -4.000000000000
8 -4.828427124746
```

Answer (score 2):

The efficient approach is to use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```
$ s='1+1+1+1=4'
$ echo ${s##*=}
4
```

See also [BashFAQ #100, on string manipulation in general](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

---

To process the entirety of a file, a `while read` loop is appropriate -- as given in [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while read -r question && read -r answer; do
  echo "${question##*=} $answer"
done <input.txt >output.txt
```